# Как вырезать только нужные цифры?

Tags: php

Есть строка типа

```
.class { width: 10px !important } .class2 {max-width:100px;} .class3 { width: 20px; }
```

Мне нужно получить только цифры **10** и **20** , то есть те которые идет после **width:** и до **px**,
но если перед width стоит символ - , значит его пропускаем.

У меня лишь удалось составить такое выражение:

```
preg_match_all('!width:(.+?)px!si', $str, $arr);
```

Но оно не работает так как мне бы хотелось...

Например, оно может извлечь мне почти всю строку от width: и до первого px, соостветвенно туда попадают остальные символы, а мне нужны только цифры если после них были символы px

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте ретроспективную проверку: [`~(?<!-)width:\h*\K\d+(?=px)~`](https://regex101.com/r/Wno362/3)

---

UPD: На PHP будет так:

```
$str = '.class { width: 10px !important } .class2 {max-width:100px;} .class3 { width: 20px; }';

preg_match_all('~(?<!-)width:\h*\K\d+(?=px)~', $str, $arr);

print_r($arr[0]);
```

[**См. демо**](https://ideone.com/PxMiOb)

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, показать это на конкретном примере?

Comment: это хорошо сработало, но не совсем так как в вопросе. не должно находить цифры если после них стоит любое другое значение отличное от **px**, например может быть width: 100%, вот это не нужно

Comment: ну так добавьте 'px'! вот: https://ideone.com/17asaY

Comment: @iKey я подкорректировал ответ.

Comment: `\K\d+(?=px)` проще в понимании что ли чем `(\d+)px` ?

Comment: @teran кому как: тому, кто не имеет представления о том или ином инструменте, нет разницы; тому, кто имеет - и то и другое понятно.

Comment: @Эдуард сложность вычисления выражения вы не учитываете? :)

Comment: @teran в регулярках я чаще всего отдаю предпочтение "чистому" результату. Но в то же время избегаю построения длинных нечитабельных шаблонов. В этом ответе шаблон не пострадал: он компактный, не слишком медленный, и возвращает исключительно необходимый набор данных. Ничего лишнего :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '.class { width: 10px !important } .class2 {max-width:100px;} ';
$str .= ' .class3 { width:   20px; } .class3 { width: -20px; }';

preg_match_all('!(?<!-)width:(\s*([1-9]\d+)\s*)px!si', $str, $arr);

print_r($arr[2]);
```

Comment: `$str .= ' .class3 { max-width: 77px; }';` , 77 тоже находит, но не должно, так как перед width стоит символ -

Comment: @iKey исправил ответ